# Add number in sequence (TextView)

Tags: java, android

I am trying to add numbers in sequence. What I mean is to have them next to each other. For example I want to have a number key pad and when the user enters a digit, it will add it to the display field etc.

For example (Display): 1738
User tapped key 1, 7, 3, 8.

From there I will add this value either double or string to a TextView. I just want each number next to each other when the person taps a button.

Thank you very much.

Comment: what code have you tried so far?

Comment: stack = stack + "1"; but instead just displays 1 instead of 1111 when I press 4 times. I would rather use a double for this instead of String.

Comment: Sorry Michael, you are going to have to do better to demonstrate what problem you are facing - we are not mind readers.

Answer (score 0):

I think you already know how to show values in TextView.

As a data structure, there are two things you can choose.

1. ArrayList
2. LinkedHashMap

I would use [LinkedHashMap](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/LinkedHashMap.html). It has uniqueness, sequence-sustaining, and can have additional `Value`.

To insert, just use `put` method as below. As HashMap gurantees only one key, it automatically detects duplicates and overwrite to new one.

```
LinkedHashMap<String, Date> hashMap = new LinkedHashMap<>();
hashMap.put("1", new Date()); // last updated timestamp is placed as a value.
```

To get inserted String value by index, use method as below.

```
public String indexOf(int position){
    return (String) hashMap.keySet().toArray()[position];
}
```

To display in TextView, use below method to occur in every key Click or Touch.

```
String output;
for(int i=0; i < hashMap.size(); i++)
{
     output += hashMap.keySet().toArray()[i];
     if(i < hashMap.size()-1)
         output += ", ";
}
textViewOutput.setText(output);
```